# how do I set images to scale to 100% of their table-cell? (C#/WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, image, anchor, sizing

I have the TableLayoutControl anchored to scale with the window and the images in it need to scale with them. I am not concerned with image quality.

Comment: Could you specify What kind of C# application?  Sounds like Windows Forms...

Comment: You mean a `TableLayoutPanel`?

Comment: Yes on both counts. Added "WinForms" to title and tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is WinForms and you have a bunch of `PictureBox`es in cells of a `TableLayoutPanel`, set each one's `Dock` to `Fill` and `SizeMode` to `StretchImage`.